# Spring boot + JavaFX : How to run tasks after start() method asynchroneously

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, initialization, startup

I'm developing a JavaFX + Spring boot app and I'm trying to figure out how to run background initialization code after JavaFX's start() method.  I have tried literally everything I can think of (and google) to try and hook into some form of initialization method but everything I tried happens before start().  The code I want to run is a series of events publishing using an ApplicationEventPublisher which start background modules.  The goal of running after the start() method is that those long-running events do not prevent the GUI from showing up and the buttons being responsive.  The best I have managed so far is putting this code at the end of JavaFX's start() method :

```
Platform.runLater(() -> 
    {
        new Thread(() ->
        {
            try 
            {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishStartupEvents();

            manageButtons();
        }).start();
    });
```

This makes the window show up and the buttons responsive ... until the code starts running that is.  Everything completely freezes for 15 seconds or so until the code is done running.  I cannot find a way to make those event calls run in the background.

Here are all the ways I found to not achieve what I want, in order of appearance of my sysouts :

```
Java Main() method
JavaFX init() method
@PostConstruct method in the main class
SmartLifeCycle start() method
ContextRefreshedEvent event listener
ApplicationReadyEvent event listener
AND_FINALLY, JavaFX start() method
```

***EDIT***

The manageButtons() method is used to enable/disable the 6 buttons I keep as global variables in the main class depending on the value of an AtomicBoolean field that is set to true by the JavaFX start() method and set to false by the JavaFX stop method() :

```
public void manageButtons()
{
    if (!headless.get())
    {
        restartCommunicationsButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        restartMessagingButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        restartMaintenanceButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        restartAdmissionsButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        restartConnectorButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        clearLogButton.setDisable(!running.get());
        shutdownButton.setDisable(!running.get());
    }
}
```

Since JavaFX's start() method is where the GUI initialization happens, I need to hook into something that happens later than that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `manageButtons()` do?

Comment: knew this would come up haha, I will add it to the post

Comment: If you're adding the `Platform.runLater` at the very end of the `start` method, it's actually unnecessary to wrap it in `Platform.runLater`. This would just delay the execution by a unspecified time. All that you could gain by this would (possibly) take measures of the GUI after the first layout pass and even that doesn't work for sure...

Comment: Here is a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125590/3992939) of a thread that is invoked after `start` and changes a 'model` that is used by the GUI. For more help post [mre]

Comment: That example is triggered by a button press, I need something that triggers automatically and is not triggered by the start() method.

Comment: Perhaps review this example [TaskBasedSplash.java](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098)

Comment: Do not modify the scene graph in your own thread (e.g. don't disable buttons from your own thread).  The reason that [`Platform.runLater`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) exists is, if you aren't on the JavaFX thread, to request something to happen on the JavaFX thread (such as your button disablement).  You'd be better off with a `Task`, binding the buttons disable state to [`running`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#runningProperty.)

Comment: OK i was able to make the initialization not freeze the GUI.  My running variable is initialized to false and set to true when the Task i created is done.  My binding to that value on the buttons doesn't work though, is this the right way to do it?  restartCommunicationsButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !running.get()));